# What about $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n s_k\mu(k)}{n}$, for the zeros of Dirichlet eta function $s_k=1+\frac{2\pi k}{\log 2}i$ with $k\geq 1$?

Tags: limits, roots, analytic-number-theory, average, arithmetic-functions

Let for integers $k\geq 1$ the corresponding zeros of **Dirichlet eta function** of the form 
$$s_k=1+\frac{2\pi k}{\log 2}i,$$ then we can consider the following puzzle, when we multiply previous equation by $\mu(k)$, its corresponding values from **Mobius function**:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n s_k\mu(k)=M(n)+\frac{2\pi i}{\log 2}\sum_{k=1}^n\mu(k)k,$$
where $M(n)$ is the evaluation of **Mertens function** at $x=n$. 
Thus 
$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n s_k\mu(k)}{n}=\frac{M(n)}{n}+\frac{2\pi i}{\log 2}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\mu(k)k}{n}.$$
Now I know that **Prime Number Theorem** is equivalent to $M(x)=o(x)$, thus exists $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{M(n)}{n}$, and this value is $0$. But

> **Question.** What about $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n s_k\mu(k)}{n}?$$

This is, you know how analyse the convergence and/or how compute the third limit involving $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\mu(k)k}{n}$.

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible start.

Since,
by summation by parts,
$\sum_{k=1}^n f_kg_k
=f_1\sum_{k=1}^n g_k+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}(f_{j+1}-f_j)\sum_{k=j+1}^ng_k
$,
if $f_k = k$,
$\sum_{k=1}^n kg_k
=\sum_{k=1}^n g_k+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^ng_k
$
so
$\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n kg_k
=\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n g_k
+\frac1{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^ng_k
$.

Setting
$g = \mu$,
$\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n k\mu(k)
=\frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k)
+\frac1{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j+1}^n\mu(k)
$.

I know this is elementary,
but it is all I can think of now.

Comment: Very thanks much @martycohen with your answer we obtain another summand $\frac{1}{n}M(n)$, great!
I to keep open the question/bounty to try to get more contributions, very thanks much for your answer, of course feel free if you want improve it.